# Traefik forwarding to a host and overriding IP

Tags: traefik

*Foreword: I appreciate that this is not ideal, I'm in the process of migrating away from an old Apache-based server, and need to leave a few sites there for now.*

I'd like to have Traefik forward certain requests to another server, consider the following config:

```
[file]

[frontends.attie]
backend = "attie"

[frontends.attie.routes._]
rule = "HostRegexp: {host:^(www\\.)?attie.co.uk}"

[backends.attie.servers._]
url = "http://attie.co.uk:80"
```

Externally, the DNS points `attie.co.uk` at this server. Traefik must then forward the request on to the old server using the `Host: attie.co.uk` header.

Unfortunately, the DNS points `attie.co.uk` to *this* server, and we end up in a loop (of course).

I've added entries to the container's `/etc/hosts`, but this doesn't work - we still end up in a loop ([see the log in this gist](https://gist.github.com/attie/5a951fbde4782f27472ad2e539bbea8e)), presumably because Traefik is doing name resolution itself and ignoring the hosts file.

---

I've tried using the `customRequestHeaders` to no avail - it appears in the config blob in the log, but doesn't work.

```
[frontends.attie.headers.customRequestHeaders]
Host = "attie.co.uk"

[backends.attie.servers._]
url = "http://10.42.0.4:80"
```

Note the warning on [this](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#custom-headers) page:

> If the custom header name is the same as one header name of the request or response, it will be replaced.

---

Is there any way I could do one of these?

- Configure the name resolution to consider `/etc/hosts`
- Force the backend to connect to a host by giving an IP alongside the `url`
- Provide a `Host:` header paired with an IP in the URL

I've had a fairly extensive look at the [documentation](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/file/), but may have missed something.

---

PS: I would have expected this question to be better suited to ServerFault or SuperUser, but they don't have the [traefik](/questions/tagged/traefik) tag, and the documentation specifically mentions StackOverflow.

Comment: Traefik links to SO from their website. I've asked them to start a Discourse forum but this is better for support and can be moved later if need be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using the official traefik image, this one is built from scratch. Most notably there is no `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file present. In this case the [golang implemented the same fallback mechanism as glibc](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/22846), which is to ignore `/etc/hosts` - which is exactly issue you are observing.

The important line in the configuration is the one, that tells the resolver to first look into local `/etc/hosts` file and then fallback to DNS query:

```
 hosts: files dns
```

The minimal `nsswitch.conf` file created by running this in the container would do:

```
echo "hosts: files dns" > /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

However considering a proper `nsswitch.conf` file is present on any normal host system, perhaps the simplest solution is to add an extra mount in your docker run. Here's the adapted example from traefik docker hub repo:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 80:80 \
-v $PWD/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
-v /etc/nsswitch.conf:/etc/nsswitch.conf:ro \
traefik
```

I'm sure you can adapt this if you use docker compose or something else. After you do that the `/etc/hosts` file inside should work as one would expect. (which you probably modified by `--add-host` docker run flag)

Comment: Sounds very promising, thanks very much... I'll try it out soon.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve this permanently is to create your own `Dockerfile`:

```sh
FROM traefik:v2.1
## Fix nssswitch not looking at hosts file (See https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/6012)
RUN echo "hosts: files dns" > /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

I have tried to [submit the change](https://github.com/containous/traefik-library-image/pull/75/files) on git but it seems the official image is hidden somewhere.